# what is all of the information eigenvalues tell us?

Tags: linear-algebra

A $3 \times 3$ matrix $B$ is known to have eigenvalues $0, 1,2$. This information is enough to find three of these (give the answers where possible):
(a) the rank of $B$
(b) the determinant of $B^T B$
(c) the eigenvalues of $B^T B$
(d) the eigenvalues of $(B^2 + I)^{-1}$

I know the product of the eigenvalues equals the determinant so I thought the rank of the matrix ould be either $1$ or $2$, but the answer key says the rank is $2$, why?
I know how to do (b) but I don't have any ideas of how to find (c) or (d), or why either of them cannout be found based on the information given?

Comment: Regarding (a), recall that eigenvectors corresponding to distinct eigenvalues are linearly independent.

Comment: For (a), right away we can see that rank($B$) cannot be 3, since $0$ is an eigenvalue of $B$ (meaning the matrix is not invertible). Also, the rank theorem can give the actual value. For (b) we see that $det(B^TB)=0$ since the matrix $B$ is not invertible, and $det(B^T)=det(B)$, and determinants are multiplicative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rank can be defined as the dimension of the space minus the dimension of the kernel... now, since $0$ is an eigenvalue the kernel has at least dimension $1$. The fact that the other eigenvalues are $1$ and $2$ (not $0$) is enough to say it is exactly one, so the rank is two.

For $B$, note that the fact that the eigenvalues are distinct implies $B$ can be diagonalized, therefore in some basis

$$B = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 &0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 &2 \end{pmatrix}$$

And you have that

$$B^2 + \operatorname{Id} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 5\end{pmatrix}$$ so the eigenvalues of the inverse are easily determined.

About (c), you can't find out what happens at $B^T B$ with just that information. Bungo's comment makes it evident with two matrices with same eigenvalues, but different $B^TB$-eigenvalues.

Comment: $A = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$ and $B = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$ are similar matrices, but $A^T A = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 4 \end{pmatrix}$ and $B^T B = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 5\end{pmatrix}$ do not have the same eigenvalues.

Comment: Of course, thank you. I will edit the above